# Scroll error (disabled) while using Chrome dev tools, possible error with JS event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Written explanation of Problem:**

*This just started happening today (10/14/15) and was not a problem yesterday.* When I go to my website http://lancedwight.com/, right click to inspect an element, and then try and scroll down through my website, the scroll functionality is disabled.  The element inspector also automatically changes from the element I was trying to inspect to the element that it thinks is causing the problem.  I know next to nothing about js so the more details you can give me to help me find a solution to this challenge the better. I can provide more information or files, if that might help you, just ask.

I thought the problem might have been caused by me accidentally fiddling with certain files, so I just asked hostgator to restore my website and database from Monday (the problem only started today, Wednesday).  But still nothing has changed.

Thanks in advance for help!

**Short video** explanation of Problem: https://youtu.be/b3cJ_ckmE4U (same video as above.)

-Lance

Comment: I could not reproduce it. What version of windows and chrome are you using? Any chrome extensions enabled?

Comment: Windows 7 and Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 m. 

My list of extensions is here: 
BackStop,
FB Pixel Helper,
Google Docs,
Google Docs Offline,
Google Sheets,
Google Slides,
Lock It, 
NoBackSpace,
SoundCloud Downloader Free, and
Web Developer.

I did find a way around the problem.  I downloaded Google Chrome Canary and the problem was eliminated.  But it is still a mystery to me why the latest edition of Google Chome is giving me this issue still, when at the beginning of the week it wasn't.